# Displaying average rating

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, asp.net-mvc-5, average

I have following two model classes

```
public partial class Items
{
    public Items()
    {
        this.Items_RATINGS = new HashSet<Items_RATINGS>();
    }

    public int ITEMID { get; set; }
    public string ITEMNAME { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Items_RATINGS> Items_RATINGS { get; set; }
}

public partial class Items_RATINGS
{
    public int ItemsID { get; set; }
    public byte ItemsRATING { get; set; }
    public string COMMENTS { get; set; }

    public virtual Items Items { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller calls, I have added

```
return View(db.Items.Include(c => c.Items_RATINGS).ToList());
```

In view, I'm calling

```
Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Items_RATINGS.Average(dr => dr.ItemsRATING))
```

However, I'm getting following error

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

How do I retireve Average Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's better to calculate the average and then pass to the view, so in you model you could have this:

```
  private ICollection<Items_RATINGS> _Items_RATINGS ;

  public double Items_RATINGS
    {
        get { return _Items_RATINGS.Average(c => c.ItemsRATING); }
        set;
    }
```

and then bind the Items_RATINGS in view:

```
Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Items_RATINGS)
```

Comment: I'm getting following error now:Additional information: Value cannot be null.